# How to join 3 tables in one sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I've these three tables :

comments :

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id   | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id      | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id      | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_text | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_date | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

     posts:

    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------
    | Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------
    | post_id       | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
    | category_id   | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | post_title    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | post_date     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | post_keywords | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | post_image    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | post_content  | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |
    | user_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------
    8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

 user:

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_user  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(35) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bio      | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_im  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| nom      | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| prenom   | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| adresse  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sexe     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_nai | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want to extract comments (from the table comments) with chosen post_id and for each user_id from the comments table , I want to extract related information from the table user , my query didn't work :

```
select comments.comments_text,comments.comments_date,user.nom,user.prenom,user_im
from comments
inner join posts on comments.post_id = posts.post_id
where comments.user_id = user.id_user;
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select comments.comments_text,comments.comments_date,user.nom,user.prenom,user_im
from comments
inner join posts on comments.post_id = posts.post_id
inner join user on comments.user_id = user.id_user;
```

Comment: that worked perfect ! thank you for the fast answer !

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if it helped you :) @RamiDridi

Answer (score 0):

@Rami you to join all the table from where you want to get respective data and also you have to mention the corresponding table name for reference to get data from them. you can try the blow query.
I hope, it will solve your problem:

```
select comments.comments_text, comments.comments_date, user.nom, user.prenom, users.user_im from comments inner join posts on comments.post_id = posts.post_id inner join user on comments.user_id = user.id_user;
```